# How can I Store a Null value in my database from a form using Entity Framework

Tags: c#

I have a data base with 2 fields to collect Date of birth and age.  Since we do not always have that data these fields are nullable. When inserting new records I use the Entity Framework and the code shown below.

```
la.DOB = DateTime.Parse(txtDOB.Text);
la.Age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
```

The process works unless either of these 2 fields have no data. The parse fails due to a null value in the string.  How can I pass the null value to the intity framework. I have tried using the `TryParse` but can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I solved the problem by changing the code to
         DateTime DOB;
         if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDOB.Text, out DOB))
         {
           la.DOB = DOB;
         }
         else
         la.DOB = (DateTime?)null;

Comment: Intity Framework? Must be new...

Comment: What is `intity framework`, are you misspelling `Entity Framework` or are you talking about some other library?

Comment: Yes sorry Scott I am using Entity Framework.  I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime.TryParse` and `int.TryParse` as you already said

```
DateTime dob;
int age;

if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDOB.Text, out dob) 
{
  la.DOB = dob
}

if (int.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out age) 
{
  la.Age = age
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the DOB and age before you create a query to execute, so EF doesn't try converting .NET methods into SQL code:

```
DateTime? dob = null;
if (txtDOB.Text == "")
    dob = DateTime.Parse(txtDOB.Text);

int? age = null;
if (txtAge.Text == "")
    age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
```

Then use those values in your query:

```
la.DOB = dob;
la.Age = age;
```

The above code assumes any data the user entered is valid. You could do additional validation, or you could use some controls that limit user input, like a DateTime picker or NumericUpDown control (depending on what platform you're designing your app).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address your question, but...

The Age property will quickly go out of date if you are not frequently updating the record. If you don't touch the record for five years, DOB will still be correct, but Age will be 5 years off.

Unless your database insists on having both values, and you do not control its schema, you might be better served to store only the DOB in the database. Age can easily be calculated in your entity object.

Comment: Great suggestion guys I will discuss these ideas with the client not sure if they want to update the age or want to know the age of the person at the time the data was entered

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to use the TryParse with an else statement to pass the null value if the form field was left blank. Here is the code if anyone else runs into this issue
    DateTime DOB;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDOB.Text, out DOB))
    {
    la.DOB = DOB;
    }
    else
    la.DOB = (DateTime?)null;